# How can I add an object to an arraylist of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

The purpose is to add teams to an arraylist. Each team is an object with a String name, String division, int wins, and int losses.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Default 
{
     ArrayList<team> teams = new ArrayList<team>();
     team Mavericks = new team("Mavericks","Southwest",50,32);
     team Rockets = new team("Rockets","Southwest",56,26);
     team Grizzlies = new team("Memphis","Southwest",55,27);
     teams.add(team Mavericks);
     teams.add(team Rockets);
     teams.add(team Grizzlies);
}
class team
{
    String name, division;
    int win,loss;
    public team(String n,String d, int w, int l)
    {
        this.name = n;
        this.division = d;
        this.win = w;
        this.loss = l;
    }

}
```

Comment: `teams.add(Mavericks);` - You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 4):

It

```
 teams.add(team Mavericks);
 teams.add(team Rockets);
 teams.add(team Grizzlies);
```

should be

```
 teams.add(Mavericks);//here Mavericks is an object
 teams.add(Rockets);
 teams.add(Grizzlies);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- Everything in `class Default` should be inside a method. Probably you wanted to do it in `main()`. Something like:

  ```
  public class Default
  {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<team> teams = new ArrayList<team>();
        team Mavericks = new team("Mavericks","Southwest",50,32);
        team Rockets = new team("Rockets","Southwest",56,26);
        team Grizzlies = new team("Memphis","Southwest",55,27);
        teams.add(team Mavericks);
        teams.add(team Rockets);
        teams.add(team Grizzlies);
      }
  }
  ```
- `teams.add(team Mavericks);` doesn't compile. You need to add to `Arraylist` like:

  ```
  teams.add(Mavericks);
  teams.add(Rockets);
  teams.add(Grizzlies);
  ```
- According to java naming convention, `team` class should be named as `Team`. Variable names should be `mavericks`, `rockets`, `memphis` instead of `Mavericks`, `Rockets`, `Memphis`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot call functions directly from the body of a class.  You should put it in a constructor instead, e.g.

```
public class Default 
{
     ArrayList<team> teams = new ArrayList<team>();
     team Mavericks = new team("Mavericks","Southwest",50,32);
     team Rockets = new team("Rockets","Southwest",56,26);
     team Grizzlies = new team("Memphis","Southwest",55,27);
     public void Default()
     {
         teams.add(team Mavericks);
         teams.add(team Rockets);
         teams.add(team Grizzlies);
     }
}
```

In addition, you should remove `team` from the invocations to `teams.add`, so they become:

```
teams.add(Mavericks);
teams.add(Rockets);
teams.add(Grizzlies);
```

I would also adhere to the Java style of starting class names with capitals and instances with small letters, e.g. `Maverick` should become `maverick` and `team` should become `Team`.  That would make it more obvious for other people which identifiers refer to classes and which to instances.  You can read more about it at [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).